# R: Use column from data as legend items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in a csv file in the following format

```
0,q20,q25,q30
0,32821,2270,68
1,105586,11366,38
2,205115,33058,50
3,311017,70664,151
4,406328,122150,434
5,482179,186786,1173
6,526470,256057,3109
7,539652,320932,6819
8,528834,374667,13208
9,503959,413366,23917
10,479126,434548,39999
11,459400,444971,61850
12,442047,450753,89661
13,419077,452288,122107
14,383514,445003,159571
15,340851,427740,198738
16,295769,401008,235076
17,252647,371289,271975
18,215557,337070,303704
19,181387,302695,329089
20,154404,270025,347097
>20,2949771,4086805,8007677
```

and I create a stacked percent barplot with the following code

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(reshape2)
    library(scales)

    data <- read.csv(file="quality.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
    datam <- melt(cbind(data[,2:ncol(data)],ind = sort(rownames(data))),is.var = c('ind'))
    datam$ind <- as.numeric(datam$ind)
    ggplot(datam,aes(x = variable, y = value,fill = factor(as.numeric(ind)))) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_fill_discrete("Bases\nunder\nQuality")+xlab("Barcode") +
    ylab("Reads")+guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(hjust=0, size=8), title="Bases Under Quality", plot.title =  theme_text(size = 16))
```

Which results in
[image]

The legend items go from "22" down to "1", but instead I would like them to go in the order specified in the first column of my data, which is from ">20" to 0". Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a parallel variable `ind1` using the values from the first column of `data` and then make sure it is an ordered factor (with the correct order). Something like this, perhaps:

```
#I'm calling that first column X0, since that's how it is imported by R
# Column names can't begin with a digit
datam$ind1 <- factor(data$X0[datam$ind],levels = data$X0,ordered = TRUE)
```

and then use `ind1` as your fill variable, rather than `ind`.

Comment: I think the last line should read "use ind1 as your fill variable, rather than ind"